# Is profit from selling various products which include red wine halal?

Tags: halal-haram, investment

Ok im asked to join this program, where we park our money in it and we are given 1-3% profit. The profits come from the buying and selling of items from different merchants in the program, from every transaction there is some processing fees and that will be used to pay the 1-3% profit.

All the products are assets based where the price could appreciate but one of the products is red wine. So is the 1-3% profit halal?

Answer (score 1):

Since the profit is coming from selling and buying products, then its Halal. Make sure that products do exists, and they are being traded.
But, because there is red wine, then its **Haram**.
Selling or Buying, delivering, or helping in the process of using Alcohol products is Haram.
So, you are getting small portion of Haram profit, in Halal profit, which makes your profit Haram.

Answer (score 0):

Short and to the point answer. Yes, it is halaal.

How? Do you snatch this 1-3% from anyone? Do you play or force others to get involved in gambling or something like that? Is that illegal, like selling drugs weaponary in black etc.

If No, then yes it is halaal.

Comment: But do I have to worry that one of its products is red wine?

Comment: @MohdIrfan, yes you need to worry here! You can either ask the Moderator of the web service to deduct any percentage being added by the objects that are haraam .. :)